# React setstate return undefined on componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

setState user property inside removeListener return undefined when i console.log() it inside component but when i check state in react developer tool user object from firebase it is there with actual value I want

```
    state = {
        coinList: {},
        fav: [],
        currentFavourite: '',
        prices: [],
        authed: false,
        user: null
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.removeListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({
                    authed: true,
                    user
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    authed: false
                });
            }
        });

        this.ref = base.syncState('fav', {
            context: this,
            state: 'fav',
            asArray: true
        });}
```

Comment: what does console.log(user) return inside if condition?

Comment: where is your console.log?

Answer (score 2):

If your console.log statement is inside the removeListener, I'd suspect that state hasn't been updated by the time console.log is called.

setState is asynchronous, so it's been updated in the background whilst the next statements are being.

You can provide setState with a function or statement that is only called once setState is completed....

```
this.setState({ user }, this.someFunction())
```

or simply...

```
this.setState({ user }, console.log(this.state.user));
```

Comment: @Sneha Bharti, thank you for pointing out the typos in my original answer.  Can only blame not being up long.

Comment: i want use user from state in my firebase rebase                             this.ref = base.syncState(`${this.state.user}/fav`, {
            context: this,
            state: 'fav',
            asArray: true
        });}        but its undefined inside it.

Comment: Did the above work in so far that you could see the state update using the callback?  If so, your comment above may be a separate question.